# Using mpirun with a provided ssh file

Tags: ssh, mpi

I am trying to run mpi on an external server. As a part of my goal, I'm attempting to run something in parallel across multiple nodes.

However, this external server has a bad default configuration file that is readonly, such that when I try to ssh to another external server without using  `ssh <server> -F ~/.ssh/config` then it will simply return four different "Bad configuration option"s. However, -F is not an option that I can use for mpirun, and I don't know if there is any way to manually change the ssh configuration file for mpirun.

What should I do?

Comment: If you are using Open MPI, try `mpirun --mca plm_rsh_args "-F $HOME/.ssh/config"` in order to have Open MPI pass extra parameters to `ssh`

Comment: I appreciate the quick response! It seems like trying to run it this way causes the server to more or less hang until keyboard interupt.

Comment: do you have any firewall running on/between the nodes?

Comment: They aren't my servers, it's a remote server that I've been allowed to use. They all share a filesystem, it would surprise me if they had firewalls between them.

Comment: Never mind! I got it to work!